# htaccess - URL rewrite - Remove slashes, but not from files

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I use PHP.

**A working htaccess-file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Look at the row with a # comment. When uncommented it adds a redirect to a slash. I use URL rewrite with [toroPHP](http://toroweb.org/).

**I want to rewrite to ending slash**

- I want to redirect to ending slash from rewritten URLs, just like the code above.
- I don't want ending slash from real files, like jquery.js, style.css.

**Example (updated 2012-12-21)**

- `/category/test` should be `/category/test/`
- `http://www.test.com/myjsfile.js` should be `http://www.test.com/myjsfile.js`

**Problem**

- If I use the code above uncommented it add an ending slash to all urls, including javascript files and css files.
- I only want the rewritten urls to end with slash.

**Question**

Can it be done with htaccess? If so how?

Comment: So you want to redirect requests for `/not/real/path` to `/not/real/path/` **and** you want to have trailing slashes on real files like scripts and styles? Your second bullet is confusing. You "don't want to remove ending slash from real files"? I don't see anywhere that adds a trailing slash. Also I tried those rules and I don't see trailing slashes getting added to my scripts and css files. Only to URI's that don't actually exist.

Comment: Yes you are right. The second bullet was not correct. I have corrected it and even added an example.

Comment: Like I mentioned, I uncomment the line and it works for me. Real files don't get affected since the 2 conditions above say "apply the rule **only** if the request is **not** for a real file or directory". I guess you could try changing it to `RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]` (what I have used in the past), but that's essentially the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The htaccess was almost correct. However the `REQUEST_FILENAME` needs to be before EVERY rewrite rule, not just before the first.

**This works**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```